# ajax with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally when I have an imput I use this syntax:

```
 ensino: $('#amount').val()
```

But now I have a group of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="1"> 
<label for="radio1">Politécnico</label> 
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="2"> 
<label for="radio2">Universitário</label> 
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="3"> 
<label for="radio3">Profissional</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" value="4"> 
<label for="radio4">Outro</label>
```

How can I do an Ajax post? In this case, I can't use the id, correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the language you're using (PHP, Python, RoR, etc.) there may be specific helpers to make this easier (certainly true for Rails). Check the docs for whichever language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be `$('*[name=radios]:checked').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ :

```
Example: send form data using ajax requests
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

You probably shouldn't be stitching together all the elements by hand, and can instead perform an ajax POST using jQuery's http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ function.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('input:radio[name=bar]:checked').val();
```